# Assign onclick="action" to text

Tags: text, hyperlink, onclick, html

I have this HTML code

```
<div id="nodate" style="display:none">
  <span id="A">
    <input type="submit" value="Close" onclick="toggle();" a href=”#”>Text</input>
  </span>
  There are no dates here. Select another.
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Fri Nov 8th, 2013" onclick="toggle();"></input>
```

I have an input for the close function which shows a button. But I want to assign this onclick action to an image or text instead of an input button. I have tried many ways but cant seem to get it.

Comment: First of all, the input element has no closing tag. Please edit the post and organize your code, so it's easier for people to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an image:

```
<input type="image" src="Image.jpg" onclick="toggle();" />
```

You could also use:

```
<button onclick="toggle();"><img src="Image.jpg" /></button>
```

Note, if you *don't* want the form to submit when you click on the button, you'd want to have:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggle();"><img src="Image.jpg" /></button>
```

For text, you could just use a hyperlink:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle();">Text</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="javascript:toggle()">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you can do that

```
$("#imgclick").click(function (e) {
  toggle();
  //even better //$("#idtarget").toggle();
});

<img src="..." id="imgclick">
```